# ProgressDialog cannot be applied to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am following a tutorial and there is a method where I get a warning.

```
// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrimaryFragmentDormir.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
```

At line

```
 mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrimaryFragmentDormir.this);
```

Android Studio shows a warning:
ProgressDialog (android.content.Context) cannot be applied to com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience.primaryFragmentDormir.

I guess this warning is not related to the ProgressDialog, it should be related to the fact that it is a Fragment and not a normal Activity, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: PrimaryFragmentDormir.this.getActivity(); (or getContext() in the newest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the context.

To get the context from a fragment call `getActivity()`:

```
new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code :

`ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrimaryFragmentDormir.this);`

to

`ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());`

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you run the `fragment` from a prinicpal `activity`, when you send calls to `fragment` as the `context` parameter (its core business).

Then use:

`mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog (context);`